# Ping devices every X minutes

Tags: batch-file

i want to ping my printers every X minutes.
why is it ignoring IF command? when it fails, it does the else command anyway

also, how to remove the milliseconds from %time% ?

```
@echo off
:loop

echo %time: =0% pinging print 1
ping 192.168.1.7 -n 3 -w 5000 > nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 1 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 1 online)

echo %time: =0% pinging print 2
ping 192.168.1.3 -n 3 -w 5000 > nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 2 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 2 online)

echo %time: =0% pinging print 3
ping 192.168.1.190 -n 3 -w 5000
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 3 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 3 online)

echo waiting 5 mins until next ping
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto loop
```

Comment: what os? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: windows 10 64bits

Comment: after you add / modify the following to your question comment to me: 1. The command and results of pinging a printer that is offline. 2. The command you are using to sleep.

Comment: I found the error in my code.  What command are you using for sleep?

Comment: using `ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > nul` to sleep (for 10 secs for testing purposes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

- Update | tested | <strike>untested</strike>  |

Using errorlevel is not a secure option to handle with ping
results output, may you can to do this job with find instead?

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && set ".=..\"

set "_loop=1" && cd /d "%~dp0" & mode con:cols=065lines=10
set "_printer_ips=1-.7,2-.3,3-.190"&& title <nul &title %0

:loop

for %%# in (!_printer_ips!)do (cd.& set "_time=!time: =0!"
for /f ^tokens^=^1^*^ ^delims^=^- %%I in ('echo/%%~#')do (
set "_time=!time: =0!"&& call set "_time= !_time:~0,5!"&&(
echo/ & set/p "=!_time! Pinging Print 0%%I^!!! ^|^| " <nul
ping 192.168.1%%J -n 3 -w 5000 -4|find /i "ttl=" >nul && (
set "_sts=Online^!") & set/p "= Printer 0%%~I !_sts!" <nul
set "_sts=OFFLINE^!" & if "%%~J"==".190" (echo/ &echo/))))


title !.!%0 Loop: 0!_loop! | set /p "=Loop: 0!_loop! "<nul
echo/^|^| Waiting 5 minutes until next pings^^!!&rem/ >nul
timeout 300 & set/a "_loop+=1"&& cls & goto:loop||goto:EOF
```

---

- Output:

  ---

```bat
14:30 Pinging Print 01! || Printer 01 Online!
14:31 Pinging Print 02! || Printer 02 OFFLINE!
14:31 Pinging Print 03! || Printer 03 OFFLINE!

Loop: 01 || Waiting 5 minutes until next pings!

Waiting for 259 seconds, press a key to continue ...
```

---

- Or, some like:

  ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion && title <nul && title ...\%~nx0 ping printers: !date! && color 9f 

:loop
for %%i in (3,7,190)do set/a "_+=1"&& set "time_=%time: =0%"&& cmd/v/c echo/ !time_:~0,5! pinging print !_! &&(
ping 192.168.1.%%~i -n 3 -4 -w 5000|find "TTL" >nul && (echo/ printer !_! online)||(echo/ printer !_! OFFLINE))
<nul cd.&echo/ waiting 05 mins until next ping^^!! & timeout /t 300 /nobreak>nul & set "_=0"&& cls &&goto :loop
```

---

- Output:

  ---

```bat
 17:04 pinging print 1
 printer 1 online
 17:04 pinging print 2
 printer 2 OFFLINE
 17:04 pinging print 3
 printer 3 OFFLINE
 waiting 05 mins until next ping!
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

How to determine if printers are online with cmd, ping, pipe, find, and if errorlevel. Does not require admin privileges.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to break out of loop

```
@title This is %~F0 at %TIME%. Are printers online?
@rem Windows 10 64-bit. Does not require admin privileges.
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
:loopqw
FOR /F "TOKENS=2-8 DELIMS=/:. " %%g IN ("%DATE%:%TIME%") DO SET ztime10=%%j:%%k:%%l
echo.
echo Ctrl+C to break out of loop.
echo.
echo %ztime10% pinging print 1
set errorlevel=
ping -n 1 192.168.1.7 | find "TTL="> nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 1 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 1 online)
echo %ztime10% pinging print 2
set errorlevel=
ping -n 1 192.168.1.3 | find "TTL="> nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 2 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 2 online)
echo %ztime10% pinging print 3
set errorlevel=
ping -n 1 192.168.1.190 | find "TTL="> nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo printer 3 OFFLINE) else (echo printer 3 online)
sleep 300 
goto :loopqw
exit /b
```

Comment: im using windows 10 64bits if it matters.
still getting printer is online even when it's not. also, had to change the sleep command otherwise there was no pause.